# Finding a better solution for comparing binary trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, ocaml

Here's a type for binary trees

```
type tree =
  | Node of tree * int * tree
  | Null;;
```

and I've got a following problem to solve:

Write a function `tree -> tree -> int` that returns a number which says for how many levels down (going from the root) the trees are essentialy the same (same values at nodes and same shapes). Here's a solution I wrote:

```
let rec identical l1 l2 =
    match (l1, l2) with
    | ([], []) -> true
    | ((tree1, s1) :: t1, (tree2, s2) :: t2) ->
         if s1 = s2 then
             match (tree1, tree2) with
             | (Null, Null) -> identical t1 t2
             | (_, Null) -> false
             | (Null, _) -> false
             | (Node (l1, x1, r1), Node (l2, x2, r2)) ->
                if x1 = x2 then identical t1 t2
                else false
         else false;;

let unfold l =
    let l = List.filter (fun (a, b) ->
      if a = Null then false else true) l in
      if List.length l = 0 then raise Nulls else
      List.fold_left (fun acc (a, b) ->
        match a with
        | Node (l, x, r) ->
            (l, "l") :: (r, "r") :: acc) [] l;;

let compare t1 t2 =
    let rec aux l1 l2 result =
        if (List.length l1 <> List.length l2)
            then result
        else
            if (identical l1 l2) then
                try
                    aux (unfold l1) (unfold l2) (result + 1)
                with
                | Nulls -> result
            else
                result
    in aux [(t1, "r")] [(t2, "r")] 0;;
```

The problem is I'm really dissatisfied with this code - it's really hard to understand, even for me. What I'm doing is essentially on every level of the tree I'm creating a list for left and right tree containing all subtrees on corresponding levels (and also whether the subtree is left or right son for determining the shape) and then comparing this list on every level. If they are identical I increment the result, if not - I return the result.

But when I use this "algorithm" I end up with this complicated code. So could it be done simplier?

Comment: You don't need to put parens in many places where you have pair expressions. Try removing some (unless it seems more readable to you?)

Comment: I heard that when putting functions in a pair, not putting parenthesess can lead to unexpected results (like OCaml thinking I want to compute the function now, not pass it as an element of the pair). That's the reason I'm always using parenthesses.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that you want to make sure the compiler will not misunderstand your intent. Basically, the comma has a low precedence in Ocaml grammar, but it turns out to be fairly OK in many cases, and avoiding them leads to lighter code (as you surely know). I suppose it's matter of taste, or maybe habit. Many people tend to avoid unnecessary parentheses, so if you read a lot of other's code, you'll probably get used to it.

Comment: Btw, I was mainly thinking about pattern matchings, when pairs are not a parameter of a Constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose the following code :

```
let rec compare_tree t1 t2 =
        match (t1, t2) with
        | (Null, Null) | (Null, _ )   | ( _ , Null ) -> 0
        | (Node (t1_l, x, t1_r), Node (t2_l, y, t2_r)) ->
                if x=y then
                        1 + min
                                (compare_tree t1_l t2_l)
                                (compare_tree t1_r t2_r)
                else 0;;
```

Two tests patterns :

```
let t1 = Node (Node (Null,1,Null),1,Node (Null, 2, Null));;
let t2 = Node (Node (Null,1,Null),1,Node (Null, 3, Null));;
let c = compare_tree t1 t2 in
        Printf.printf "compare = %d\n" c
        ;;

let t1 = Node (Node (Null,1,Null),1,Node (Null, 2, Null));;
let t2 = Node (Node (Null,1,Null),1,Node (Node (Null,1,Null), 2, Null));;
let c = compare_tree t1 t2 in
        Printf.printf "compare = %d\n" c
        ;;
```

The first test returns 1 : only the level 1 (int 1) is the same in both trees, but but on level 2, the subtrees that are on the rights differ  (2 vs 3).
The second test returns 2 since the head is the same, and the 2 subtrees have same value, what differs next is the additionnal subtree.
Is it the correct expected behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, tests are correct. Thanks for your code, that's exactly what I wanted my solution to look like.

Answer (score 2):

A better algorithm is just to do a standard depth-first search.  Stop and back up when you either a) find a difference, or b) hit the depth where you have already found a difference in a previous branch.